# Is Bhagavad Gita a success manual?

Tags: gods, bhagavad-gita, life, gita

A lot of people I see refer to Bhagavad Gita as success manual, many successful  people like Dr. Vivek Bindra, Mahatma Gandhi, and even Einstein. Have referred to it.
Does Bhagvad Gita prepares us for success in Life?

Comment: Your question suffers from survivorship bias. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias  Who knows how many people followed the gita but failed? Their stories will not come out because they have failed.

Comment: @LazyLubber But thats true for any success manual! And here we are interested in what the Scriptures say and not about individual experiences:)

Comment: @commonman OP is citing individual experiences.

Comment: @LazyLubber yes, but the Q here being asked must be about scriptural reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course. The last verse of Gita mentions it:

> •18.78 **Where there is Krsna, the Lord of yogas, and where there is Partha, the wielder of the bow, there are fortune, victory, prosperity and unfailing prudence. Such is my conviction**.

What else is meant by 'Success' ?

Comment: Sanjaya said this. Yeah.